# Change environment settings in unit tests (Angular)

Tags: angular

I can think of two approaches when dealing with settings in `Angular`:

1. DI settings using `InjectionToken` [as per the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injection-token).
2. Environment files, where I have settings for each environment (dev, qa, prod), I import the generic "environment" file, and I compile with a flag that sets the environment.

When unit testing, I'm used to #1: I just create settings appropriate for my unit tests and inject them.

But how could I change the settings if I go with #2? Say that I need to mock a setting. Can I add an environment flag when running the unit tests?

Comment: Why don't you simply combine the two approaches: an injectable, mockable service, whose implementation returns values from the environment?

Comment: I see. So keep the injectable settings and still use the environment values. Do you know if there is any way to use #2 for unit testing? I would think not...

Comment: Well yes, there is. Just set the environment values before your test (i.e. `environment.someSetting = 'someTestValue'`). But mutable global state is generally a bad idea. Using an injectable, mockable service is meant to avoid that.

Comment: I see, I missed to consider that I can just change the value, but I also agree that's not a good idea. Well, thanks so much!